# rubik's cube inside a rubik's cube

Tags: rubiks-cube

Once I completed solving Rubik's cube, **a different pattern** came into my mind. It was-

```
A B B
A B B
A C C
```

Here, same letters represent same colors. So is it possible to get this pattern in a Rubik's cube on all of it's faces?

Comment: ...without dismantling it, correct?

Comment: @Raystafarian I think it's  perfect here. Rubik's cube is a puzzle. And if you have a answer, post it,

Comment: @Kingrames, you can dismantle it. I've tried alot to get this pattern even by dismantling it but I couldn't.

Comment: @Raystafarian your given sequence is another Rubik's Cube to solve. Can you give more information on your answer?

Comment: My intuition says it's impossible but I think it is very hard to prove

Comment: Is the mirror image allowed? So one side might be `ABB|ABB|ACC` and another is `EED|EED|FFD`?

Comment: @tfitzger no, mirror image is not allowed. every face must be ABB | ABB | ACC.

Answer (score 3):

This will be our model cube *(just so we're all on the same page of the face (center block) colors)* -

[image]

I've been trying to work on this, but I don't know enough math to formulate a rule. But, given the pattern -

```
A B B
A B B
A C C
```

We can note that each block of 4 that match in the upper right, it has 3 matches to its **left** (depending on which way you hold the cube). Let's make our blocks of 4 and indicate which matches are to the left -

[image]

*Note that the colors I picked are arbitrary, it will work out the same way if you choose different corners.*

As you can see, all of the triples to the left match with another triple to the left, thereby requiring two corner pieces that match 2 colors **and** an edge of those matching colors.

**Pairs**

```
yu
vx
wz
```

We also know what *color pairs* those corners *can't* have so they don't match their own face -

```
zw - yellow, red
vx - green, white
uy - orange, blue
```

The corners we have left:

```
BOY
GRY
RBY
BOW
GRW
GOW
```

How they can match to our pairs -

```
zw - BOY, BOW, GRW, GOW
vx - BOY, GRY, RBY, BOW
uy - GRY, RBY, GRW, GOW
```

So the pairs that are possible are

```
zw - BOx, GWx, OWx
vx - BOx, BYx, RYx
uy - RYx, GWx, GRx
```

With the blocks that remain, every color is present on exactly **3 corners** and **2 edges**.

Let's give a variable name to the other matches that there needs to be -

[image]

I don't see any combination of the cubes we have left that will meet the required matching criteria. But I can't formulate a *proof* of this. Maybe someone else can?

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is a similar situation listed here:

http://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/rubiks-cube-patterns-algorithms/
(Twisted cube in the big cube)

However it's not a match, you have two faces with swapped colors.

Hopefully this link will assist in your efforts. If nothing else, maybe someone can add some more relevant information. I confess I am no expert on Rubik's cubes (I know how to do the checkerboard thing though!)

(If you edit this post, be sure to comment so your contributions don't get forgotten!)